# Export a file by showing Save As Dialogue

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, savefiledialog

```
string fileName = "1001-1000-1_29_2015 2_04_22 PM.wav";
string filePath = Server.MapPath("Audio") + "\\" + fileName;
```

In IE, I used the following line to export my .wav file.

```
Response.Redirect("Audio/" + fileName);
```

As `Response.Redirect();` is used to redirect the user to anything (pages, files etc). So in IE it shows an `SaveAsDialogue` to the user to save it.

But in chrome, the default behavior of the browser is to redirect to the specified file and plays it in the chrome.

I want to export my `.wav` file by giving a `SaveAsDialogue` in both browsers.

I tried the following code for chrome:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "Audio/wav";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

But still I'm not successful to transmit my `.wav` file in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll sort it; by changing the mime-type of the content to a generic one:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Edit:  Here's the exact code I'm using and it works with WAV files too:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName);
Response.WriteFile(file);
Response.End();
```

The **save to dialogue** is a client side feature that cannot be forced*. Only reason IE offers it in the first instance is because it doesn't know what to do with the file when trying to access it directly. The above method is to force it to download, not play/render directly in the browser. **However** you can right click the link(s) and select `Save link as...`.

*I suppose if you were to set the mime-type up incorrectly on the server for the file type then use your original `Response.Redirect` method then you could but you'd be messing with the server and causing no end of headaches down the line.

If you want to change Chrome to ask you every time where to save a download to you need to to into **Settings**, click *Show advanced settings...* then scroll down to the **Downloads** heading where you'll see something like this:

[image: Downloads Setting in Chrome]

Comment: I have already checked it for my downloads in Chrome and in my case it didn't effect it.

Comment: **Your edited answer, still not working in case of exporting audio file in any format.**

Comment: Not working in what way? Is it just not downloading? Or are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: By using your both ways, **IE** and **Chrome** both not responding. No error message, no prompt, nothing at all...

Comment: The code provided is from a working example so there has to be something else wrong on your page. The first version is the same as your original but with the content type switched out so I don't see how that's stopped the page from working at all.  You really need to step through with the debugger and see what and where it's failing.

Comment: Also in conjunction with `Response.Clear();` you may also want to add `Response.ClearHeaders();` afterwards, this will clear any content type header already set to the page